# Width event only for tablet

Tags: jquery

Testing my website I am facing a little issue (not really important, but would appreciate if he has any solution):

I am using the following code to redirect users to mobile version and also deleting a `data-attribute`.
CODE:

```
if (screen.width <= 480) {
    document.location = "/mov/index.php";
}   
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    location.replace("/mov/index.php");
}
if ($(window).width() > 1023) {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore', 'false');
} else {
    $('#content').removeAttr('data-snap-ignore');
}
```

The first part is not the main problem, so focusing on the following event, there goes my question:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1023) {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore', 'false');
} else {
    $('#content').removeAttr('data-snap-ignore');
}
```

**How could I set only the width event for tablets?**

Also thought about user agent, but seems like will be a trouble with android tablets (since mobile and tablets have got the same user agent).

Comment: Have you looked at CSS media queries?

Comment: Yep, i am using media queries, the problem comes when I only want the event data-snap on tablets

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('#yourTableSelector').width()
```

But you would need to add it into the `resize` event if you want it to work when resizing the window.

Comment: I tried with resize option, but seems like it's working aswell for tablets and deskopts screens (since testing on ipad uses the same resolution)